# MySQL, Order by + every other row

Tags: mysql

Not sure if it has been asked before but not sure what to look for. So here is the problem:

A MySQL table contains fields

```
A, B, C, D

A is 1 or 0
B is 1 or 0
C is 1, 2, 3 or 4
D is a date
```

So far, B was ignored and the 'order by' was:

```
A DESC, C DESC, D ASC
```

Now what is wanted is to have

```
A DESC, B "1 every other row else 0", C DESC, D ASC
```

So we would get rows ordered like

```
[A, 1, C, D]
[A, 0, C, D]
[A, 1, C, D]
[A, 0, C, D]
[A, 1, C, D]
[A, 0, C, D]
[A, 1, C, D]
[A, 0, C, D] // last 0
[A, 1, C, D]
[A, 1, C, D]
[A, 1, C, D]
```

Any idea how to do it in SQL? It's about selecting rows with this order, so SELECT ... ORDER BY ...

Thanks!

Comment: Consider providing proper CREATE and INSERT statements, and a corresponding desired result.

Comment: Not sure what you mean? It's about selecting data with a certain order.

Comment: OK. Good luck with that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `order by` needed:

```
order by 
    A DESC, 
    IF(B = 1, 2*(@odd := @odd + 1), 2*(@even := @even + 1) + 1),
    C DESC, 
    D ASC;
```

Following is a complete demo.

## SQL:

```
-- data
create table t1(A INT, B INT, C INT, D date);
insert into t1 values
(1,1,1,'2016-01-01'),
(1,1,2,'2016-01-02'),
(1,1,3,'2016-01-03'),
(1,1,4,'2016-01-04'),
(1,1,1,'2016-01-04'),
(1,1,2,'2016-01-05'),
(1,1,3,'2016-01-06'),
(1,0,4,'2016-01-07'),
(1,0,1,'2016-01-08'),
(1,0,2,'2016-01-09');
select * from t1 order by A DESC, C DESC, D ASC;

-- query wanted
select t1.* 
from t1 CROSS JOIN (select @even := 0, @odd := 0) param
order by 
    A DESC, 
    IF(B = 1, 2*(@odd := @odd + 1), 2*(@even := @even + 1) + 1),
    C DESC, 
    D ASC;
```

## Output:

```
mysql> select * from t1 order by A DESC, C DESC, D ASC;
+------+------+------+------------+
| A    | B    | C    | D          |
+------+------+------+------------+
|    1 |    1 |    4 | 2016-01-04 |
|    1 |    0 |    4 | 2016-01-07 |
|    1 |    1 |    3 | 2016-01-03 |
|    1 |    1 |    3 | 2016-01-06 |
|    1 |    1 |    2 | 2016-01-02 |
|    1 |    1 |    2 | 2016-01-05 |
|    1 |    0 |    2 | 2016-01-09 |
|    1 |    1 |    1 | 2016-01-01 |
|    1 |    1 |    1 | 2016-01-04 |
|    1 |    0 |    1 | 2016-01-08 |
+------+------+------+------------+
10 rows in set (0.00 sec)

-- query wanted
mysql> select t1.*
    -> from t1 CROSS JOIN (select @even := 0, @odd := 0) param
    -> order by
    -> A DESC,
    -> IF(B = 1, 2*(@odd := @odd + 1), 2*(@even := @even + 1) + 1),
    -> C DESC,
    -> D ASC;
+------+------+------+------------+
| A    | B    | C    | D          |
+------+------+------+------------+
|    1 |    1 |    1 | 2016-01-01 |
|    1 |    0 |    4 | 2016-01-07 |
|    1 |    1 |    2 | 2016-01-02 |
|    1 |    0 |    1 | 2016-01-08 |
|    1 |    1 |    3 | 2016-01-03 |
|    1 |    0 |    2 | 2016-01-09 |
|    1 |    1 |    4 | 2016-01-04 |
|    1 |    1 |    1 | 2016-01-04 |
|    1 |    1 |    2 | 2016-01-05 |
|    1 |    1 |    3 | 2016-01-06 |
+------+------+------+------------+
10 rows in set (0.00 sec)
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for your answer!